# How to implement list of connected users on all TCP clients

Tags: c#, serialization, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

I am trying to code a way in which I can display to each tcp client a list of connected users which are connected to the server.

Things tried:
I have tried to convert the list array to a single variable which connects all items within the array using a comma ",". Then I send the variable to all clients using a broadcast method which displays a message.

My question is that if there is a better way of doing this.

The code I have tried is shown below :

Inside server :

```
NetworkStream stream= tcpclient.GetStream();  
var bytes= stream.Read(bytes, 0, tcpclient.ReceiveBufferSize);
nameUser= Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes);

var users= String.Join("x", userList);
Console.WriteLine("Connected users " + users);
ChatServer.Broadcast(users, nameUser, false);
```

The message is then broadcasted which in this case the message is "users".

On the client:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[10025];
stream= Client.GetStream();
var byte= Netstream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)Client.ReceiveBufferSize);
string msg= Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, byte);
if (msg.Contains("x") == true)
   {
    elements = msg.Split(new[] { 'x' });
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `String.Contains` for detecting a message like this is a very bad idea.

You may consider some leading bytes (or characters) in your message that correspond to the message type. 
For example, if you assign 5 characters for that, you could start every message that is about online users with `USERS`. You should build some other conventions for that. But I guess you could also find some sort of standards for communicating these messages.

In addition, it is more usual to use `byte[]` instead of characters. So you could assume a standard that your first e.g., four bytes is related to message type and your e.g., second two bytes shows the user ID and so on. You may use `short`, `int`, or `long`  for codes related to these things and use `Enumeration types` to organize them.

Note that when you use a first number of bytes to detect type of the message and other things, you can write your further code in a way that depends on these message characteristics. Whatever you do, do not use `Contains`; a message could contain anything, you can't detect its type by that!

Comment: if i were to add USERS for any message regarding user then would i still use String.Contains to read from it so that a specific code is run within my client. I am abit confused with the second part of ur explaination regarding "e.g., four bytes is related to message type and your e.g., second two bytes shows the user ID and so on" could you prehaps demonstrate it within an example so I can get a better understanding.